# Validate django form with local files

Tags: django, forms, file-upload, pytube

My web page has the option of upload videos using a form, but I wanted to extend its functionalities adding the option of giving a YouTube URL instead of uploading a file.

With the file upload there is no problem, as I validate the form from a model:

**forms.py**

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Video
        fields = ('file', 'description', 'url')
```

**models.py**

```
class Video(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=video_directory_path)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

and everything works fine, but when I try to do that sending the video's URL, the `form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)` won't work by itself as request.FILES is empty, but I tried many things like:

```
form = VideoForm(request.POST,
                 MultiValueDict({'file': [open(fname,'r')]}))
```

and VideoForm always returns:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_file">File:</label></th><td><ul class="errorlist"><li>No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.</li></ul><input type="file" name="file" required id="id_file" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_description">Description:</label></th><td><textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="40" id="id_description">
</textarea></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_url">Url:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="url" value="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kj7wTDK5Vx8" id="id_url" maxlength="255" /></td></tr>
```

The question is, there is a way to set `request.FILES` with a local file for validating a form? I use the **pytube** library in order to download a video, and it works fine because it displays a bit stream when I do `open(fname,'r').read()`, and `open(fname,'r')` returns `{'file': <open file u'markst.mp4', mode 'r' at 0x7f375b654db0>}`

I hope my issue is clear, and thanks in advance!

Comment: can you upload your form in template?

Comment: can you try adding  enctype="multipart/form-data" in your html form tag ?

Comment: @hathlogic the problem is handling the video downloaded from a URL in the backend. With the video upload from a file there is no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the Django's `File` object in the following way:

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDict

file = open(fname, 'r') # Reads the downloaded video
fileform = File(file)
form = VideoForm(data=request.POST, files=MultiValueDict({'file': [fileform]}))
```

With this, the form object finally passes the validation when doing `form.is_valid()`.

I hope this helps someone with the same problem I had.